# delete specific rows from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataset and i want to delete specific rows. What I want is to keep the index 0 delete the index 1, keep the index 2 delete the index 3 and so until the end of the dataset. I expect in the end to have the half dataset. On example of the dataset is the following

```
    activity    accx    accy          accz         gyrx       gyry          gyrz
0   sitting 0.285583    0.936890    -0.104187   -3.647104   2.385671    -0.137195
1   sitting 0.280151    0.948547    -0.106018   -3.700457   2.580030    -1.162348
2   sitting 0.278381    0.945007    -0.103149   -3.727134   3.003049    -0.586890
3   sitting 0.285706    0.943237    -0.103088   -4.043445   5.171494    -0.472561
4   sitting 0.290283    0.943298    -0.102722   -4.382622   7.378049    -0.289634
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the rows you want to delete.

```
df.drop([1,3], axis=0)
```

For a general solution you can use `np.arange`

```
df.drop(np.arange(1,len(df),2), axis=0)
```

Use the `inplace` argument, if memory is scarce

```
df.drop(np.arange(1,len(df),2), axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dfevens = df.iloc[0::2].copy()
```

Just use iloc to filter only the even indexs.

Comment: And of you overwrite df it can be garbage collected.